# Generate an Map containing an Intersection/Union of values contained in two maps Map<X,Set<Y>>

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, set

I have two map arguments: `Map<X,Set<Y>> map1` and `Map<X,Set<Y>> map2`.

I am looking for a way to write a method that generates a *new map* containing an *Intersection* of *values* for *keys* that are present in both maps, and a *Union* of *values* for *keys* that are present either in `map1` or `map2`.

In other words, for any `X x` if it is in the domain of `map1` but not in the domain of `map2`, then its value will be `map1.get(x)`. Same in the opposite case. If it is in both of them, then I would like to return a set that is the intersection of `map1.get(x)` and `map2.get(x)`.

Assuming I know which class `X` is, this can be done with the following code:

```
public Map<X,Set<Y>> unifyAndIntersect(Map<X,Set<Y>> map1, Map<X,Set<Y>> map2) {
    Map<X,Set<Y>> combined = new HashMap();
    combined.putAll(map1);
    for(X x : map2.keySet()){
          if(combined.contains(x)){
                Set<Y> res = Sets.newSet();
                res.addAll(map1.get(x));
                res.retainAll(map2.get(x));
                combined.put(x,res);
          }
          else{
                combined.put(x,map2.get(x));
          }
    }
}
```

However, I would like to make this method generic, in a sense that it will work for any `X` and `Y`. I have tried using `Object`, but get an error converting from my class type to `Object`...

Could you advise me on what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: A generic method requires that you define the generic variables. Other than that I don't see where your problem is. Just don't use `new HashMap()` but `new HashMap<>()`.

Comment: To write a generic function in Java, you use '*generics*'. Start with [a tutorial on those](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). Your current function also doesn't return anything, despite being declared to.

Comment: Ofcourse union-intersection is a name I came up with. It means that for any x, if only one map contains it, then that will be the result. If both maps contain it, we return the intersection of their sets, that's why I used retainAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to declare a generic method, you need to provide generic type parameters `<X,Y>` between method modifiers and return type ([*for more information, see*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)). Without that `X` and `Y` in the map type `Map<X,Set<Y>>` would not be treated as generic "placeholders" for types, but as types itself and the compiler will complain that types `X` and `Y` are unknown.

Don't forget the [*diamond* `<>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) on the right side, while instantiating a generic class, `new HashMap();` without a diamond creates a map of *row* type.

There's also an inconsistency in the code you've provided: if a key is present is both maps a *new set* would be added as a value into the resulting map, but if the key is contained only in one of them according to your code an existing set would be used. I would better to ensure that subsequent modifications of the values of the resulting map will have no impact on the state of `map1` and `map2` by generating a new set for every value.

```
public <X,Y> Map<X, Set<Y>> unifyAndIntersect(Map<X,Set<Y>> map1,
                                              Map<X,Set<Y>> map2) {
    
    Map<X, Set<Y>> combined = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<X, Set<Y>> entry: map1.entrySet()){
        Set<Y> union = new HashSet<>(entry.getValue());
        if (map2.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            union.retainAll(map2.get(entry.getKey()));
        }
        combined.put(entry.getKey(), union);
    }
    return combined;
}
```

The same logic can be implemented using Stream API:

```
public <X,Y> Map<X, Set<Y>> unifyAndIntersect(Map<X,Set<Y>> map1,
                                              Map<X,Set<Y>> map2) {
    return map1.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> {
            Set<Y> set2 = map2.get(entry.getKey());
            return set2 == null ? Map.entry(entry.getKey(), new HashSet(entry.getValue())) : 
                Map.entry(entry.getKey(),
                entry.getValue().stream()
                    .filter(set2::contains)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But instead of union.addAll(map2.get(entry.getKey()) I would like union.retainAll(map2.get(entry.getKey())

Comment: @BenicioAgüero Sorry for this misunderstanding, I've updated the answer and improved the editing of your question. Let me know if something is still incorrect.